# ¿Cómo hacer una herencia visual con windows forms?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-forms, formularios

Tengo varios formularios que se parecen y se me ha ocurrido hacer un formulario base con las características más o menos comunes para que el resto hereden de ese formulario. Para ello he:

1. Creado un formulario base normal y corriente.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2. Compilado la solución.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que cuando quiero añadir un nuevo formulario heredado me sale una ventana donde tengo que seleccionar el formulario del que quiero que herede el nuevo pero me sale vacío.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea de por qué?

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que limpies tu solución(ir al **explorador de soluciones** y dar clic derecho en el nombre de la solución y en el menú contextual que se despliega dar clic en la **opción Limpiar solución**), posteriormente compilas tu solución. También debes revisar que tanto el formulario base como los formularios que hereden de este pertenezcan al mismo proyecto, en caso de estar en proyectos diferentes debes añadir la referencia correspondiente del proyecto del formulario base en el proyecto del formulario que hereda.